# Got elasticsearch monitoring broken in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring

One day my Kibana started to show that monitoring is switched off and it can't switch it on again.

[image]

In kibana's logs there is such messages:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-04-07T06:35:58Z","tags":["debug","monitoring-ui","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":1,"message":"Uploading bulk stats payload to the local cluster"}
Unhandled rejection [export_exception] Exception when closing export bulk :: {"path":"/_xpack/monitoring/_bulk","query":{"system_id":"kibana","system_api_version":"6","interval":"10000ms"},"body":"{\"index\":{\"_type\":\"kibana_stats\"}}\n{\"kibana\":{\"uuid\":\"c1f81ebc-9b7f-47c0-90ce-47b44725ad25\",\"name\":\"kibana\",\"index\":\".kibana\",\"host\":\"0\",\"transport_address\":\"0:5601\",\"version\":\"6.6.1\",\"snapshot\":false,\"status\":\"green\"},\"usage\":{\"kql\":{\"optInCount\":1,\"optOutCount\":0,\"defaultQueryLanguage\":\"default-lucene\"},\"index\":\".kibana\",\"dashboard\":{\"total\":2},\"visualization\":{\"total\":3},\"search\":{\"total\":5},\"index_pattern\":{\"total\":7},\"graph_workspace\":{\"total\":0},\"timelion_sheet\":{\"total\":0},\"spaces\":{\"available\":true,\"enabled\":true,\"count\":3},\"apm\":{\"has_any_services\":false,\"services_per_agent\":{}},\"infraops\":{\"last_24_hours\":{\"hits\":{\"infraops_hosts\":0,\"infraops_docker\":0,\"infraops_kubernetes\":0,\"logs\":0}}},\"rollups\":{\"index_patterns\":{\"total\":0},\"saved_searches\":{\"total\":0},\"visualizations\":{\"total\":0,\"saved_searches\":{\"total\":0}}},\"xpack\":{\"reporting\":{\"available\":true,\"enabled\":true,\"browser_type\":\"chromium\",\"_all\":0,\"csv\":{\"available\":true,\"total\":0},\"PNG\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"printable_pdf\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"status\":{},\"lastDay\":{\"_all\":0,\"csv\":{\"available\":true,\"total\":0},\"PNG\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"printable_pdf\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"status\":{}},\"last7Days\":{\"_all\":0,\"csv\":{\"available\":true,\"total\":0},\"PNG\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"printable_pdf\":{\"available\":false,\"total\":0},\"status\":{}}}}},\"cloud\":{\"name\":\"gcp\",\"id\":\"7164592281880898911\",\"vm_type\":\"custom-6-25600\",\"region\":\"us-central1\",\"zone\":\"us-central1-c\"},\"concurrent_connections\":0,\"os\":{\"load\":{\"1m\":0.61181640625,\"5m\":0.49462890625,\"15m\":0.46142578125},\"memory\":{\"total_in_bytes\":26338160640,\"free_in_bytes\":1914593280,\"used_in_bytes\":24423567360},\"uptime_in_millis\":1684000,\"platform\":\"linux\",\"platformRelease\":\"linux-4.14.91+\",\"distro\":\"Centos\",\"distroRelease\":\"Centos-7.6.1810\"},\"process\":{\"event_loop_delay\":1.137755999341607,\"memory\":{\"heap\":{\"total_in_bytes\":200716288,\"used_in_bytes\":160904432,\"size_limit\":1526909922},\"resident_set_size_in_bytes\":290590720},\"uptime_in_millis\":1209623},\"requests\":{\"disconnects\":0,\"total\":6},\"response_times\":{\"average\":131,\"max\":131},\"timestamp\":\"2019-04-07T06:35:57.046Z\"}\n","statusCode":500,"response":"{\"took\":10,\"ignored\":false,\"errors\":true,\"error\":{\"type\":\"export_exception\",\"reason\":\"Exception when closing export bulk\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"export_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to flush export bulks\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"export_exception\",\"reason\":\"bulk [default_local] reports failures when exporting documents\",\"exceptions\":[{\"type\":\"export_exception\",\"reason\":\"RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch-master-1][10.8.2.14:9300][indices:admin/create]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Rejecting mapping update to [.monitoring-kibana-6-2019.04.07] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [item, doc]];\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Rejecting mapping update to [.monitoring-kibana-6-2019.04.07] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [item, doc]\"}}]}}}}"}
```

I think that the most important part is "Rejecting mapping update to [.monitoring-kibana-6-2019.04.07] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [item, doc]"

Supposedly it happened after we had a performance issue and elasticsearch-client node restarted.

How could I fix this?

UPD:
https://gist.github.com/korjavin/2c7031b83b777b27a7a4b4a63590b556

templates for kibana and es

Comment: please send kibana index template. _template/.monitoring-kibana

Comment: I've just added the gist with templates.

Comment: please delete this index: .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.04.07 and restart kibana. and check the log again. thanks.

Comment: it assume that the index have been created and kibana try to create it again.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I deleted index and template and restarted kibana, I've got the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we found the problem.
One developer created a template with index match like index_patterns: ['*']
And it broke kibana monitoring.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: lol, the same. really interesting